# How do I bind to Spinner.SelectedItem

Tags: xamarin.android, reactiveui

I would like to bind the selected text from a spinner to a string named SelectedRole in my ViewModel. This is what I did

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SelectedRole, v => v.roleSpinner.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

However, I ran into an exception.

```
System.NotSupportedException: Index expressions are only supported with constants.
```

Comment: You have to use ToString as a conversion parameter, rather than part of the actual binding. Since Bind is two-way, it will ask you for both a vm-v conversion and a v-vm conversion. So something like this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SelectedRole, v => v.roleSpinner.SelectedItem, x => x.ToString(), [string to item conversion]);

Comment: Check to make sure that you need the Two way Bind, if OneWayBind works for you use that it will simplify this problem.

Comment: @ColtBauman: I don't think so, it still gives me that same exception. I suspect that because of the property SelectedItem of roleSpinner is a Java.Lang.Object and ReactiveUI doesn't support this type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *SelectedItem* property of Spinner has read-only access (no setter), so Bind won't work since it's two-way.

One alternative is to install the ReactiveUI.Events package and use the *ItemSelected* observable like this:

```
_spinner.Events().ItemSelected
    .Select(_ => _spinner.SelectedItem.ToString())
    .BindTo(ViewModel, x => x.Selected);
```

and of course the view model property is reactive:

```
private string _selected;
public string Selected
{
    get => _selected;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selected, value);
}
```

and if you want to initialize the spinner value, use the *SetSelection* method:

```
_spinner.SetSelection(2);
```

I tested all this on my phone and it works as expected. Let me know if this functionality fits your needs.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case for .NET 6 MAUI versions. XAML Bindings to SelectedItem do indeed work.